# having trouble with abs(x) in final answer of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the ODE I am studying
$$\dot{y} = y^2-2xy+x^2,$$
which I solve by the changes of variable $$y-x=u$$
The changes of variable leads to the following equation
$$
\begin{split}
\dot{u}+1 = u^2 & \implies  \mathrm{d}x = \left(-\frac{\frac12}{u+1} + \frac{\frac12}{u-1}\right)\mathrm{d}u\\
& \implies c\cdot e^{2x} = \left|\frac{u-1}{u+1}   \right|
\end{split}
$$
so at this point my question is how do I remove the flat brackets $|\cdot|$ from my final answer to get an explicit form $y=f(x)$ form for my final answer ?

Comment: You could separate the solution into regions where you know the sign.

Comment: can you be specefic and explain it more please  ?

Comment: Look at $u> 1$, then $\bigg | \frac{u-1}{u+1} \bigg | = \frac{u-1}{u+1}$. You can then solve for $u$ and thus $y$. Do the same thing for $-1 < u < 1$ where $|u-1| = 1 - u$, etc.

Comment: I'd recommend not using "$*$" to denote multiplication. "$\cdot$" (```\cdot```) is much better, and can be made bigger to denote a dot product by typing ```\boldsymbol{\cdot}```.

Comment: considering what u said  for $$u>1,u<-1$$ which leads to $$y>x+1,y<x-1$$ we have an answer but how should we demonstrate this answer exactly i mean how should we show the domian for each solution is it enogh to just say $$y>x+1,y<x-1$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The left side of
$$
c\cdot e^{2x} = \left|\frac{u-1}{u+1}   \right|
$$
is never zero for $c\ne 0$. This implies that the sign of $\frac{u-1}{u+1}$ must be continuous, and thus constant. Now join the sign as factor with the constant factor $c$, to get
$$
C\cdot e^{2x} = \frac{u-1}{u+1}
$$
where $C\in\Bbb R$ is arbitrary. This can now be easily solved for $u$.